# PHP Mathematical Equation with multiple functions in it

Tags: php, math

I have a mathematical question with PHP. Where n is a positive integer, this function f(n) satisfies the following.

[image: a question](http://imgur.com/IqTBP9o)![]

This is a question asked in my programming class and now I am now trying to create a program to find f(n) using PHP, but now I am confused because this equation contains more than one function and I do not know how to put this in PHP. If you have any idea on how to put this equation into some codes, please post your idea. I would like to know how to write php code to solve this kind of mathematical equations.

Comment: its good to post your code what you have tried to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look closely to the equation you will find this is Fibonacci Series.you can solve this using recursive function Like this.

```
    function fib($n) {
        if ($n < 0) {
            return NULL;
        } elseif ($n === 0) {
            return 0;
        } elseif ($n === 1 || $n === 2) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return fib($n-1) + fib($n-2);
        }    
    }
```

As you can see i am  calling same function until the base condition satisfied. Hope this help

Comment: Thanks a lot! Last time I faced fibonacci was about 10 years ago, so literally haven't seen for years. You reminded me of a great math genius.